# XSL:FO for-each creating fixed size loops

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

lets say we have a list of values f.e. 99 values and we hate to go through them using for-each four times taking 30 values each time and then operating with those values.

```
<xsl:template name="30valuestemplate">   
<xsl:for-each select="values">  

   ...

</xsl:for-each>
</template>
```

so how to call this template 4 times that it would only take 30 values each time, use a counter perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is the XSLT way of doing this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <nums>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </nums>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num[position() mod 30 = 1]">
  <group>
    <xsl:copy-of select=".|following-sibling::*[not(position() > 29)]"/>
  </group>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="num"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted result (every consecutive group of 30 `num` elements wrapped in a separate `group` element) is produced**:

```
<nums>
   <group>
      <num>01</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
      <num>07</num>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
      <num>10</num>
      <num>01</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
      <num>07</num>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
      <num>10</num>
      <num>01</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
      <num>07</num>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
      <num>10</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>01</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
      <num>07</num>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
      <num>10</num>
      <num>01</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
      <num>07</num>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
      <num>10</num>
      <num>01</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
      <num>07</num>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
      <num>10</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>01</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
      <num>07</num>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
      <num>10</num>
      <num>01</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
      <num>07</num>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
      <num>10</num>
      <num>01</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
      <num>07</num>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
      <num>10</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>01</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
      <num>07</num>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
   </group>
</nums>
```

Comment: how do you know this stuff? also maybe could you answer fop memory leak question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582563/multiple-page-sequence-objects

Comment: @Greed: Just read good books on XSLT/XPath. You can find a list of good resources here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar example of dividing a big loop to fixed size sections (limited to 3 per iteration). It generates an HTML table with 3 columns, but you can easily modify it for your needs.

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
............
<xsl:call-template name="list-3-groups-after">
<xsl:with-param name="n" select="1"/>
<xsl:with-param name="values" select="30valuestemplate"/>
</xsl:call-template>
.............
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="list-3-groups-after">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:param name="values"/>
    <xsl:if test="values[$n]">
    <tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="render-value">
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$values[$n]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="render-value">
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$values[$n + 1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="render-value">
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$values[$n + 2]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </tr>
    <xsl:call-template name="list-3-groups-after">
        <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n + 3"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="values" select="$values"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template> 


<xsl:template name="render-value">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <td valign="top">
         <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged `xslt-2.0`, here's a stylesheet using `xsl:for-each-group` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping) on [Dimitre's sample document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10583739/4092205):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <nums>
       <xsl:for-each-group
           select="*"
           group-starting-with="num[position() mod 30 = 1]">
         <group>
           <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
         </group>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
     </nums>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```